# Select Case Month previous

Tags: excel, vba, format, conditional-statements, monthcalendar

I am looking for help to solve this problem below.

I have created a code that has to get the information from many excel files received daily, but with dates, today -3 or -5 depend on the day of the week. No problem with that, but as you can see in the code below my issue is when I have a new month, for example, 1st of December the Macro will consider the month as of December, but actually, the file received still from November.

How can I use the select case for Macro to find the excel file, if not in the actual month do to the previous month?

```
Select Case Weekday(Now)

Case Is = vbThursday, vbFriday

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _

    "Z:\Risk Management\reports\Risk reports\" & Year(Now) & "\" & Format(Now, "mmmm") & "\" & Format(Now - 3, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "\Investmentfonds_-Insurance_Bond_Opportunities_-_Report_" & Format(Now - 3, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"

    Case Else...
```

Comment: Can't you just change `& Year(Now) & "\" & Format(Now, "mmmm") &` to & `Year(Now-3) & "\" & Format(Now-3, "mmmm") &`?

Comment: Use the `DateAdd()` method with a negative value. `reportDate = DateAdd("y", -5, Date)` This will return the date you need to format. If today's date is the 1st of December, will go back to November of the previous year.